# Setting @print rules in CSS is giving margins even though my elements are of the same size in PX

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page

I'm trying to generate a printable div that I set to `5400px 7200px` in size. This is meant to be printed on an 18" by 24" paper at 300ppi. The issue however is when it comes to printing it, the page shows margins even though I set `@print size: 5400px 7200px` as well.

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 5400px 7200px;
    margin: 0mm;
  }
}
html, body {
  width: 5400px;
  height: 7200px;
}
```

Even with this CSS, the print comes out as the following at `4050px 5400px` so only 225ppi and with white margins (see photo below). Is there a CSS setting I'm missing somewhere?

[image: Printed PDF comes out with margins]

Comment: Don't set any fixed width. Also keep in mind that printers may have their own margins set somewhere.

Comment: To clarify, how do I go about removing width? I tried change it to `size: auto 7200px` but now it just defaults to A1